# How to get 10HP heal with medikit

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

The XCOM Wikia [Temple Ship Assault](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Temple_Ship_Assault) page mentions that one could take a Field Medic Support to get medikits that heal 10HP. Below is the quote:

> At least one Field Medic Support with Savior and Improved Medikits 
>   (for option to heal 10 HP) will likely be crucial for survival 
>   and mission success.

After completing the [Improved Medikit](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Improved_Medikit)  Foundry project, one gets *the health recovered by the use of a Medikit increased from 4 to 6.*

**How do I get the medikit improvement from 6 to 10HP?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- The basic Medikit heals 4HP.
- The [Improved Medikit](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Improved_Medikit) foundry project adds an extra 2HP.
- The [Savior](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Savior) skill (Colonel-level option for Support) adds an extra 4HP.

All of these together give a total of 10HP per heal.

As noted in the comments, in Enemy Within there's also a medal that can add 2HP to heals received by the wearer - so a Support Colonel with Improved Medikit could heal a wearer of that medal for 12HP.

Comment: In the Enemy Within expasion there's also a medal with an option that bestows another +2 healing *received* to the wearer.

Comment: @Shadur thanks, have added (belatedly!) to the answer.